# How to change the date format when displaying the result?

Tags: php, date, datetime, format

In the database, date format is `Y-m-d`, I'm trying to display my result with this format `d-m-Y`.

This is my code:

```
<input name="personal_ic_from" type="text" class="tcal" id="personal_ic_from" value="<?php echo $personal_ic_from ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Comment: sorry.. there is my code.

Comment: echo $date->format($personal_ic_from,'Y-m-d');
also, u can check this http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: date in C:\wamp\www\eprofile\dashboard.php on line 320, i get this error

Answer (score 1):

Follow the procedural style in php

```
<?php
$databaseDate = '2013-09-29 01:02:03';
$date = date_create($databaseDate);
echo date_format($date, 'd-m-y');
?>
```

You can also try **`strtotime()`**

```
<?php
$queryResultDate = mysqli_query("SELECT column_name FROM table_name"); //selecting the  date column
 $date = date("d-m-y" , strtotime($queryResultDate));
echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: this code will echo the date for today.. i want it echo the date on my database that i saved.

Comment: @afifi: this is the example. Replace `$databaseDate` with your variable `$personal_ic_from`.

Comment: @Glavić, i try it, the result is  2013-09-29 01:02:03, but my $personal_ic_from in my database is 2013-09-01. i required to echo that value(date value) from the database in this format d-m-Y and $personal_ic_from type is date not datetime

Comment: @afifi: yes, because you copy/pasted the above code, and didn't change anything, ccc. Try: `echo date_create($personal_ic_from)->format('d-m-Y');`

Comment: @Glavić, ok thx bro.. i understand now.. if i want to update the date, i still need to convert back ?

Comment: @Glavić, this my update query mysql_query("UPDATE personal_id_ic SET personal_ic_from = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["personal_ic_from"])."' WHERE LAS_login_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["LAS_login_id"])."'"); i still need to convert back from d-m-Y to Y-m-d?

Comment: @afifi ofc. If you have [standard date format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) (which currentlly is) you can convert it back in the same maner. For unknown formats look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2167925/67332).

Comment: @Glavić, i cant understand link for the answer.. can u show me, where should i put the format converter code inside my update query?? it will be big help for me because i need to finish my assignment and i stuck here..

Comment: @afifi - You need to put the format converter code for the variable which you want to send to the update query.The above code is just a sample for converting date formats in php  and you can do by that way.